# SQL query to filter multiple conditions

Tags: sql, teradata, where-clause

#I want to add a filter for model_no such that if. I define a bunch of models, for example(fasd, wqeqwe) it should only populate those in the table. Help me build this query#

```
SELECT  
E.T2580_GIN_ID AS GTIN_ID,    
E.T1989_CRY_CD AS CountryCode,    
E.T4478_SEL_ATR_NBR AS Attribute_NO,    
C.T616_VBU_NBR AS VBU_Number,    
B.MOD_IDF_TXT AS MODEL_NO,    
C.T024_ITM_NBR AS Item_No,    
J.T2591_BAR_CD_ID AS Barcode,    
E.ATR_VAL_CHR_TXT AS LPD        
FROM TABLE.T4484_GIN_ATR_LAG  E    
JOIN TABLE.T2594_GIN_VBU_ITM C     
ON (C.T2580_GIN_ID = E.T2580_GIN_ID)    
JOIN TABLE.T2580_GIN_VBU B    
ON (E.T2580_GIN_ID = B.T2580_GIN_ID)    
JOIN TABLE.T2591_GIN_BAR_CD J    
ON (E.T2580_GIN_ID = J.T2580_GIN_ID)    
WHERE E.T1989_CRY_CD IN (1,5)    
AND E.T4478_SEL_ATR_NBR = 3208    
(    
SELECT B.MOD_IDF_TXT    
FROM LOWES.T2580_GIN_VBU B     
WHERE B.MOD_IDF_TXT = 'PA091M35'    
)    
;
```

[image: outputTable]

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Please show needed output as text

Answer (score 0):

### Got the answer using Double AND

---

```
SELECT      
E.T2580_GIN_ID AS GTIN_ID,    
E.T1989_CRY_CD AS Country_Code,    
E.T4478_SEL_ATR_NBR AS Attribute_NO,    
C.T616_VBU_NBR AS VBU_Number,    
B.MOD_IDF_TXT AS MODEL_NO ,    
C.T024_ITM_NBR AS Item_No,    
J.T2591_BAR_CD_ID AS Barcode,    
E.ATR_VAL_CHR_TXT AS LPD    
FROM TAble.T4484_GIN_ATR_LAG  E    
JOIN table.T2594_GIN_VBU_ITM C     
ON (C.T2580_GIN_ID = E.T2580_GIN_ID)    
JOIN table.T2580_GIN_VBU B    
ON (E.T2580_GIN_ID = B.T2580_GIN_ID)    
JOIN table.T2591_GIN_BAR_CD J    
ON (E.T2580_GIN_ID = J.T2580_GIN_ID)    
WHERE E.T1989_CRY_CD IN (1,5)    
AND E.T4478_SEL_ATR_NBR = 3208    
AND B.MOD_IDF_TXT IN  ('PA091M35','10019')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).